# Running VSS 2005 Client on a the same server as VSS 6.0

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

Is it possible to run client-server combination of VSS 2005 (client)/VSS 6.0 (server) on the same box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. I've been doing it for about a year with no problems

Comment: yes. our organization runs vss6 but is soon to get an update to 2005. I have both clients and both servers on my own box.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that should work just fine. I don't believe the client and server share any components and I am able to use VSS 2005 to connect to VSS 6.0 databases.